# Calling the plugin with parameters in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have build a java class which calls the plugins.The structure of my application is

[image: Application Structure]

Here Plugin folder contains different packages and each package contains the Plugins.Plugin App contains Main.java which calls the Plugin jar ,AbstractPlugin.java contains 2 abstract methods and PluginLoader.java checks the plugins present in config.cfg file and Loads the plugin.In config.cfg all the plugin jars are present as key value pair.
Code for Main.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.example.plugincall.AbstractPlugin;
import com.example.plugincall.PluginLoader;
import com.example.plugincall.PluginLoader.PluginData;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final File plugin_list = new File("C:\\Users\\RajendraPrasadH\\eclipse-workspace\\PluginApp\\src\\config.cfg");

        try {
            PluginLoader.parseConfig(plugin_list, null);
            System.out.println("Success of calling PluginLoader.parseConfig");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final HashMap<String, PluginData> plugin_datas = PluginLoader.getPlugins();
        System.out.println("plugin_datas contain" + plugin_datas);
        final AbstractPlugin[] plugins = new AbstractPlugin[plugin_datas.size()];
        System.out.println("The plugins are " + plugins);
        try {
            int i = 0;
            for (String key : plugin_datas.keySet()) {
                plugins[i++] = PluginLoader.newInstance(plugin_datas.get(key));
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (AbstractPlugin plugin : plugins) {
            plugin.start();
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (AbstractPlugin plugin : plugins) {
            plugin.interrupt();
            try {
                plugin.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            plugin.close();

        }

    }

}
```

Code for AbstractPlugins.java

```
package com.example.plugincall;

public abstract class AbstractPlugin extends Thread {

    @Override
    public abstract void run();

    public abstract void close();
}
```

Code for PluginLoader.java

```
package com.example.plugincall;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class PluginLoader {
    public static class PluginData {
        public final String name;
        public final String pack;
        public final URL file;
        public final Class<?> cache;

        public PluginData(String name, String pack, URL file) throws ClassNotFoundException {
            this.name = name;
            System.out.println("Name inside PluginData is" + name);
            this.pack = pack;
            System.out.println("Pack inside PluginData is" + pack);
            this.file = file;
            System.out.println("File inside PluginData is" + this.file);
            cache = Class.forName(this.pack, true, new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { this.file }));
        }
    }

    final private static HashMap<String, PluginData> data = new HashMap<>();

    public static void parseConfig(File file, String plugin_root) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        System.out.println("BufferedReader executed in PluginLoader");
        String in;
        int line = 0;
        while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("br.readLine() value is" + in);
            line++;
            System.out.println("Value of in.isEmpty()" + in.isEmpty());
            if (in.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            final String[] split = in.split(" ");
            System.out.println("value of split is" + split[1]);
            if (split.length < 2) {
                br.close();
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not split line in configuration file" + in + " on line " + line);

            }
            System.out.println("calling data");
            if (data.get(split[0]) != null) {
                br.close();
                throw new RuntimeException("Atempt to replace loaded plugin" + split[0] + " on line " + line);
            }

            data.put(split[0],
                    new PluginData(split[0], split[1], new File(plugin_root, split[0] + ".jar").toURI().toURL()));
        }
        br.close();
    }

    public static AbstractPlugin newInstance(PluginData data) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println("The value of (AbstractPlugin) data.cache.newInstance() is" + data.cache.newInstance());
        return (AbstractPlugin) data.cache.newInstance();

    }

    public static HashMap<String, PluginData> getPlugins() {
        System.out.println("value of PluginLoader.data is" + PluginLoader.data);
        return PluginLoader.data;
    }

}
```

config.cfg contains

```
Plugin1 com.plugins.Plugin1
```

I need to pass a string argument when the call to Plugin is made.This string argument which should be passed to the plugins is received from another file and it should be passed to the plugin when it is called.I have made changes in the Plugin to accept a string argument .What changes should i make in the java files so that i can also pass a parameter while calling the Plugin and I'm running it in eclipse in Windows and not cmd.

Comment: Not sure to understand the issue: `plugin.setArgument(argument)` before `plugin.start()` wouldn't do the job? (you would have to implement this method) You may also want to add an additional method: `plugin.start(argument)`

Comment: Where should I add this plugin.start() method?

Comment: You're already using it in `Main.java`. Weren't you talking about this method call when you said "[...] the plugin when it is called"?